# loading smaller image in mobile device(small screen)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, responsive-design

Recently i have seem articles that mention about it is advisable to load smaller size image in mobile device when using responsive web design.

Let say i have a product image that is uploaded by client(high definition image). What approach can i use to load this image of smaller size into the client side browser(other than create a duplicate of image of smaller size). Or the way that most developer did is to create a duplicate image of smaller size?

Maybe we can do it in server side to reduce the image size before user load the image? but will this affect server performance?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should resize the image when it is uploaded and store the different versions on the server. Then when clients request your website from different browsers you would adjust and select the proper image to be included. You would also avoid the CPU intensive dynamic image resize on each request.

Comment: i see, i thought that it is not advisable to have duplicate image of different place at the first place. so this is the common practice in industry?

Comment: You would load it and then use server side solutions, like adaptive-images, or others to serve up the image for that device. If you use adaptive-images it automatically detects the device and serves the size that won't be too big for that device.

Comment: @myfinite Darin(THE answer person according to his rep) is not suggesting loading up on to the page two or more image sizes and hiding one or showing it based on the viewport width, he's suggesting that when the image is loaded that a server side script sizes it accordingly and then when a user visits the site from a small device an image sized appropriately for that device is shown.